# Passport and Visa Expiration Inquiry

Tags: china, visa-expiration

I am an international student studying in China. My current visa will expire on September 25, 2018. Interestingly, my passport will expire on March 18, 2019. What can I do?
I basically need a 6months visa and have plans to go back home in January for renewal.
Is it possible to go to my embassy for a stamp?

Comment: Welcome to TravelSE. Please add all relevant to the question by clicking on [edit]. You should at least tell us your nationality and explain `"I need a 6 month visa"` remark - do you want to extend your Chinese visa or do you need a visa of another country?

Comment: Your embassy can't help you with a Chinese visa. You have to apply through the Chinese authorities. The international student office at your university should be able to advise you. You might also get a fuller answer on [expatriates.se], where they have more expertise in long term visas and migration.

Comment: @Cannon, thanks for your response. I actually intend to go to the embassy for my passport extension. I will then go to get the Chinese authorities to get the Chinese visa extension...